# Set the event.startDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata

This is my code! But event.startDate return 2012-12-29 18:05:00 +0000

data is a string = "04-12-2012"

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",data,oraInizio]];
 NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",data,oraFine]];

event.startDate=date;
event.endDate=date2;
```

Why 2012-12-29 and not 2012-12-04 ??

This is the complete script

```
- (IBAction)aggiungiEvento:(id)sender {

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
     // iOS 6 and later
     [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted){

            EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
            event.title     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ al %@",tipoLocale,nomeLocale];

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"];

            NSLog(@"%@   %@",data,oraInizio);

            NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",data,oraInizio]];
            NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",data,oraFine]];


            event.startDate=date;
            event.endDate=date2;

            [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *err;
            [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

             NSLog(@"%@  %@",event.startDate,data);

        }else
        {
            //----- codes here when user NOT allow your app to access the calendar.
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: event is initialized in thi way  EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have used `@"YYYY"` when you should have used @"`yyyy`" in the year part of your format.

Note that even after you fix that, your time may still be wrong if you don't do something about specifying the time zone.

Comment: ohhhh! Yes the problem was yyyy ! The hour is not correct when do NSLog(@"%@",event.startDate); there is 1 hour of difference! I'm in Italy! However in calendar the data is correctly passed !!?? Its a good think but strange